# Effect of HOME on libreoffice to convert to pdf as non-root user

Tags: linux, centos, libreoffice

I installed libreoffice-headless and can convert documents when logged on as root.  I then tried doing so as another user, and it didn't show an error, but didn't convert the file.  I then found that if I get rid of the `HOME=/tmp/ayb`, it works with the other user.  Doesn't `HOME=/tmp/ayb` just allow files to default to this directory if not specified? (Sorry, I tried to search "Linux HOME", but as you probably expect, received a bunch of non-relevant results).  If not, what is the purpose of specifying `HOME`?  Why does setting `HOME` prevent it from converting on non-root users?  Note that /tmp and /tmp/ayb or both 0777.  Thank you

```
[root@desktop ~]# yum install libreoffice-headless
[root@desktop ~]# yum install libreoffice-writer
[root@desktop ~]# ls -l
total 48
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 NotionCommotion NotionCommotion 48128 Jul 30 02:38 document_34.doc
[root@desktop ~]# HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
convert /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc -> /tmp/ayb/document_34.pdf using writer_pdf_Export
[root@desktop ~]# rm d*.pdf
rm: remove regular file `document_34.pdf'? y
[root@desktop ~]# /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
convert /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc -> /tmp/ayb/document_34.pdf using writer_pdf_Export
[root@desktop ~]# rm d*.pdf
rm: remove regular file `document_34.pdf'? y
[root@desktop ~]# su NotionCommotion
sh-4.1$ HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
sh-4.1$ rm d*.pdf
rm: cannot remove `d*.pdf': No such file or directory
sh-4.1$ /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
sh-4.1$ rm d*.pdf
rm: cannot remove `d*.pdf': No such file or directory
sh-4.1$ exit
exit
[root@desktop ~]# su NotionCommotion
sh-4.1$ /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
convert /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc -> /tmp/ayb/document_34.pdf using writer_pdf_Export
sh-4.1$ rm d*.pdf
sh-4.1$ HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
sh-4.1$ rm d*.pdf
rm: cannot remove `d*.pdf': No such file or directory
sh-4.1$ /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
sh-4.1$ rm d*.pdf
rm: cannot remove `d*.pdf': No such file or directory
sh-4.1$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have really no idea what you are trying to do here.

- `$HOME` is your user's home directory, why would you change that to run a program?
- You are explicitly telling libreoffice to create a pdf in the directory `/tmp/ayb` which does not seem to be your current directory. You are then attempting to delete a pdf from your current directory and, of course, it does not exist because you have told it to place it in `/tmp/ayb`.

What happens if you do not change `HOME` or your user or anything else and just run:

```
$ libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
$ ls /tmp/ayb/d*.pdf
```

Comment: I wasn't sure that `$HOME` changed the home directory, but was blindly told to do so some time in the past and don't recall the details.  Thanks for clarification.  Yes, I am explicitly specifying directories, so it is likely redundant.  The purpose of showing `rm d*.pdf` was just to show viewers that it definitely wasn't created.  If I do not change `HOME`, it works great.  Why does changing `HOME` cause problems only for non-root users?

Comment: @user1032531 it _was_ created exactly where you told it to be, have a look at `/tmp/ayb/`, it should be there. You are specifying an output directory, that is where the created file will be. Anyway, changing `$HOME` changes where the system will look for your personal configuration files and will wreak havoc with just about everything. Don't do it.

Comment: My end goal is to do this with PHP, and thus will run under user "apache".  I just tried to run the above shell script using PHP, and it didn't convert the file.  NotionCommotion had a default home but apache does not.  I think that is why I previously specified HOME.

Comment: For instance, `[root@desktop ~]# su -s /bin/sh apache -c "/usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc"` does not convert the document.  Why? Is a HOME needed?

Comment: Yes a HOME is needed but no for the command you are attempting. Just leave HOME alone, don't touch it :). Also, stop being root, go back to your normal user and just run `libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc`. That will create `/tmp/ayb/document_34.pdf`. That's all you need.

Comment: Thanks Terdon,  Yes, that script will run as a "normal" user, but not as apache.  For instance, `<?php shell_exec('/usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc'); ?>` doesn't convert the file, because it is running as apache.  `su -s /bin/sh apache -c "..."` was just to test whether it would work for apache without showing any php.  I believe that is why I had been including the `HOME=/tmp/ayb` command, but now see it made no sense when running as a normal user.  Problem is I still cannot convert the file when running as apache without a home.

Comment: @user1032531 could you please rewrite your question explaining what you are trying to do? How does apache enter into this? If you are attempting to do something through the web server, you need tell us how you are doing it. Using `su` to switch to the apache user will fail since `apache` is not a regular user and has no entry in the `/etc/password` file. So, basically, start at the beginning, [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Terdon,  My question kind of changed based on your remarks.  You did answer my original question, but not what it turned out I really needed.  I will post a brand new question, and hope you will comment/answer it.  Thank

Comment: New similar but different question is located at http://superuser.com/questions/627266/convert-file-to-pdf-using-libreoffice-under-user-apache-i-e-when-using-php